# Navigation by category in app with compound entity model in asp.net mvc 3

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, linq, entity-relationship

I need to filter products by categories and provide link to each category.
This is the  method from StoreController:

```
public ViewResult Content(string category = null, int page = 1)
    {
        var model = new StoreContentViewModel
            {
                Items = _itemsRepository.GetItems()
                .Where(i => i.Product.Category == category || i.Product.Category == null)
                .OrderBy(i => i.ItemId)
                .Skip((page-1)*PageSize)
                .Take(PageSize),

                PageInfo = new PageInfo
                    {
                        TotalItems = category == null ? _itemsRepository.GetItems().Count() :
                        _itemsRepository.GetItems().Where(i => i.Product.Category == category).Count(),
                        CurrentPage = page,
                        ItemsPerPage = PageSize
                    },

                CurrentCategory = category
            };
        return View(model);
    }
```

And here is the method from NavigationController:

```
    public PartialViewResult Menu(string category)
    {
        ViewBag.SelectedCategory = category;

        IEnumerable<string> result = _itemsRepository.GetItems()
                                     .Select(i => i.Product.Category)
                                     .Distinct()
                                     .OrderBy(i => i);

        return PartialView(result);
    }
```

Partial View for this Menu method:

```
@model IEnumerable<string>

@Html.ActionLink("All products", "Content", "Store")

@foreach (var link in Model)
{
@Html.RouteLink(link,
   new
   {
       controller = "Navigation",
       action = "Menu",
       category = link,
       page = 1
   },
   new
   {
       @class = link == ViewBag.SelectedCatgory ? "selectedLink" : null
   }
   )

}
```

In my model 1 item contains 1 product (ProductId is the foreign key in Items table). When I run the app I get an error: "The value  cannot be equal to null or empty. Parameter name: controllerName". Unit test for this action method also fails.
Without adding categry filtering everything works.

I think the problem is in lines where I get "Category" property from the _itemsRepository, (cause "filter" unit test also fails):

```
_itemsRepository.Product.Category
```

Is it right? If it is I want to know is there any other way to access "Category" property??
Thanks in advance.

**Edit:**
Message error was caused by wrong routing.
Items cannot still be selected by categories, the problem is definitely associated with this line:

```
Items = _itemsRepository.GetItems()
                .Where(i => i.Product.Category == category || i.Product.Category == null)
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you using entity framework as your ORM?  If so entity framework does not load related objects for you automatically.  You have to tell it you want the objects to be loaded.  You can do this by using the Include() method to eagerly load your properties.  Check out the answer I put on this question.  Very similar.

[How to access child entity's property in a where clause of linq expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14052199/how-to-access-child-entitys-property-in-a-where-clause-of-linq-expression/14055339#14055339)