# How to access child entity's property in a where clause of linq expression?

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

I've already asked similar question but it was not very precise, so I will do it again.

Suppose I have a model where one entity includes other entity. Is there any way to access a property of child entity withing a linq query?  Here is the example:

```
string category = "something";

IEnumerable<string> Items = _itemsRepository.GetItems()
                .Where(i => i.Product.Category == category)
                .OrderBy(i => i.ItemId);
```

In a clause "Where" I want to access child entity's property "Category", (this chunk of code doesn't work). Table "Items" contains foreign key "ProductId" of table "Products".
So here I want to select items which product's category equals "something". How can it be done?

Thank You in advance!

Comment: can we see the model code ?  If the navigation properties are ok, then the code looks ok.

Comment: I used linq to sql model first approach, the code was autogenerated by database model. You think that the problem is in model?

Comment: yopu tagged it EF ?  is it EF or metal ?

Comment: Can you update the question with the error you're getting (compile time or runtime)

Comment: When I pass "Items" to other method, run the app and access this method, the ArgumentException occures: "the value cannot be equal to null or empty". Seems like the query returns no items

Comment: IEnumerable<string> looks strange. Why not IEnumerable<Item> ? What about ...OrderBy(i => i.ItemId).ToList() to force the execution of the query against the sql server ?

Comment: tried IEnumerable<Item> and ToList() - didn't work. If remove "where" clause everything will work, so I think the problem is in "where" expression

Comment: There is no way you can assign your "Items" to the IEnumerable<string> with or without the where clause.. either "select" a string property, or change the type of the variable you are assigning to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
IEnumerable<Item> Items = _itemsRepository.GetItems()
                .Where(i => category == null || 
                           (i.Product != null && 
                            i.Product.Category == category))
                .OrderBy(i => i.ItemId);
```

Comment: hi! Thanks for answer! But what if I have method (that wraps this chunk of code) and I pass "category" as a parameter to this method. So I also want to be able to get all items (of all categories).

Comment: Updated the linq for that.

Comment: @AlekseiChepovoi - It will as long as Product is never null but if it ever is then you will get a null reference exception when you execute the query.

Answer (score 1):

As others suggested in their comments providing more info about the error will help us answer your question.

Are you getting a null reference exception?

If so, make sure you are including your child entity/navigation property in the linq statement or query that is being executed in the method `_itemsRepository.GetItems()`.

Entity framework won't load your related objects unless you tell it to.  I recommend that you eagerly load your property using the [`.Include()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738708.aspx) method.  You need to do this as part of whatever query you are executing inside of `GetItems()`.   You can also use lazy loading to get access to your sub properties.  Here is an article that explains it some.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh205756.aspx

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a select clause

```
    IEnumerable<string> Items = _itemsRepository.GetItems()
            .Where(i => i.Product.Category == category)
            .OrderBy(i => i.ItemId)
            .Select(i => i.Name); //<- or whatever string property you expect to get out
```

Otherwise, you should not have `IEnumerable<string>` but rather `IEnumerable<Item>` or what your entity is called.